# Apache2 using PHP 5.4 while 5.6 is installed

Tags: php, apache, debian, apache2, raspbian

I'm currently using **Raspbian Wheezy 7.0** right now.  Since `PHP 5.6` is not available on the apt repositories for wheezy, I decided to build it from source.  The build worked perfectly, I didn't receive any errors from it.

So when I used `php -v` it gave me the following output.

```
PHP 5.6.10 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2016 09:23:21) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Ok, I thought.  Perfect, everything is updated like it should be.

Here's where the problem comes in.  For some reason, when I use `phpinfo()` on my apache2 server.  It says that I'm still on version `5.4.45`.

My first guess was that the module apache was using `libphp5.so` located in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/` was out of date.  But, I have no idea where the `libphp5.so` module is for the new php version that I just installed is.

It'd be great if anyone could help me with this or point me in the right direction.  I'm using Apache version `2.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your console, `php -v` is the **CLI binary**. When building PHP you can build many different binaries for different SAPIs (*Server APIs*), one of them being CLI. Apache2 Handler or mod_php would be another one. In order to build your PHP as an Apache httpd module you need to make sure you include the `--with-apxs2` configuration option when compiling from source. This means running `./configure --with-apxs2` before you `make; make install;` the binary. You then need to make sure to load the newly built `libphp5.so` or `mod_php.so` (however you built it) to the appropriate directly and load it from your Apaache httpd config. Where your newly compiled binaries are stored, depends on your compile time configuration options and environment, but typically they are located in `$PREFIX/$HOME/bin`. So for example, if you compiled `--with-prefix=/usr` you might get `/usr/php/bin/libphp5.so`, but typically the binary is moved for you by `make install`. You do need to make sure you restart httpd for the newly built binary to be loaded.

See the [PHP manual on installation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) for more details.

Comment: It's telling me to specify an apxs path.  However, I don't know of any path for apache.  I installed it using `sudo apt-get install apache2`.  So I wasn't able to configure it with --enable-so.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your path to your Apache httpd web server binary. `apxs` is the program that's used to build extensions for your Apache httpd webserver. If it's asking for the path you most likely don't have apxs installed. You'll probably need to check your packagemanger to see if you have apxs2 installed first. If it is already installed it's not registering properly in the environment variables so you'll need to specify the path to apxs2 manually.

Comment: FWIW, this question probably belongs on Super User not StackOverflow. It's not a programming question.

Comment: Oh, I apologize.  Should I delete this question?  I appreciate your input.

Comment: One last question, have you any idea where the module will be installed?

Comment: Stated in the answer. It should be installed the right place where you have your httpd modules. `make install` will tell you exactly where it moved it.

Comment: The MySQLI class doesn't seem to work anymore.  I know this question doesn't belong here, but do you have any idea of what I should do about this?

Comment: Never mind, I just configured it with `--with-mysqli`.